# Sort nvarchar in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with this data in SQL Server :

```
Id
=====
1
12e
5
```

and I want to order this data like this:

```
id
====
1
5
12e
```

My `id` column is of type `nvarchar(50)` and I can't convert it to `int`.

Is this possible that I sort the data in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd actually use something along the lines of [this function](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/13/sql-server-udf-function-to-parse-alphanumeric-characters-from-string/), though be warned that it's not going to be super-speedy. I've modified that function to return only the numbers:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UDF_ParseNumericChars
(
  @string VARCHAR(8000)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @IncorrectCharLoc SMALLINT
  SET @IncorrectCharLoc = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @string)
  WHILE @IncorrectCharLoc > 0
  BEGIN
    SET @string = STUFF(@string, @IncorrectCharLoc, 1, '')
    SET @IncorrectCharLoc = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @string)
  END
  SET @string = @string
  RETURN @string
END
GO
```

Once you create that function, then you can do your sort like this:

```
  SELECT YourMixedColumn
    FROM YourTable
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, dbo.UDF_ParseNumericChars(YourMixedColumn))
```

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, if you *ever* find yourself manipulating parts of columns, you're almost certainly doing it wrong.

If your ID is made up of a numeric and alpha component and you need to fiddle with just the numeric bit, make it two columns and save yourself some angst. In that case, you have an integral `id_numeric` and a varchar `id_alpha` and your query is simply:

```
select   char(id_numeric) | id_alpha as id
from     mytable
order by id_numeric asc
```

Or, if you really *must* store that as a single column, create extra columns to hold the individual parts and use those for sorting and selection. But, in order to mitigate the problems in having duplicate data in a row, use triggers to ensure the data remains consistent:

```
select   id
from     mytable
order by id_numeric asc
```

You usually *don't* want to have to do this splitting on every select since that never scales well. By doing it as an update/insert trigger, you only do the splitting when needed (ie, when the data changes) and this cost is amortised across all the selects. That's a good idea because, in the vast majority of cases, databases are read far more often than they're written.

And it's perfectly normal practice to revert to lesser levels of normalisation for performance reasons, *provided* that you understand and mitigate the consequences.

Comment: Doesn't directly answer the question, but +1 for "If you ever find yourself manipulating parts of columns, you're almost certainly doing it wrong."

Comment: Actually, the second and third paragraphs answer the question: change the schema. Everything else is a band-aid solution :-)

Comment: I don't consider "change the schema" a *direct* answer.  Though I do consider it the *correct* one :).

Answer (score 0):

It can be sort with the Len function

```
 create table #temp (id nvarchar(50) null)
 select * from #temp order by LEN(id)
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he's looking for - how would this sort `1` before `5` ??